# Drawing and labeling a triangle for a demonstration for the Law of Cosines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have provided the code for a triangle having vertices A, B, and C. The lengths of the sides are to be labeled a, b, and c.  The altitude of the triangle is to be drawn as a dashed line segment from A to line segment BC, the foot of the altitude is to be labeled P, the height is to be labeled h, and a right angle mark is to be put at the foot.  The length of PC is to be labeled x, and the length of PB is to be labeled b-x, and these labels are to be inside the triangle.  There are now two smaller triangles that are similar to each other.  One pair of angles that have equal measure are to be labeled with an arc having a "peg" through it; the other pair of angles that have equal measure are to be labeled with an arc having two "pegs" through it.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
mydot/.style={
  fill,
  circle,
  inner sep=1.5pt
  }
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]

% the coordinates of the vertices
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (100:4cm);
\coordinate (B) at (20:5cm);

% the edges of the triangle
\draw (C) -- (A) -- (B) -- cycle;

% labelling the vertices
\node[mydot,label={left:$A$}] at (A) {};
\node[mydot,label={right:$B$}] at (B) {};
\node[mydot,label={below left:$C$}] at (C) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Andrew Indeed, the same user asking the same question.

Comment: @user60254 Please do not ask the same question again. If you are not clear about something in the solution you accepted there, ask for clarification in a comment or post a follow-up, linking that question in your new question.

Comment: @cfr Hadn't noticed that it was the same user...

Comment: I did ask for clarification but didn't get a response.  How do I  post a follow-up, linking a question in my current post?

Comment: I would like to have an obtuse triangle drawn. The height is to be drawn with a dashed line, and a dashed line segment from one of the vertices to the foot of the line segment indicating the height of the triangle is to be drawn.  Such a diagram would use much of the code present in the code for the diagram in this post.  How do I post a follow-up, linking a question in my current post?